# How to divide Windows 8 into two mini desktops

Tags: windows

[image]

This is an example of split screens. I want to move 'brackets' to the right where all that blue is. How do I drag it onto the right side? Im trying to do what I did in order to pull up the split option to begin with, but it just won't let me.

Sorry if this isnt meant to be placed in the wrong stack site. I looked all over and thought this stack section is most suitable. I'm a web designer. I want to be able to watch videos and control most of chrome in the left part of my screen and edit code on the right. Without conflicting windows popping up or overlaying.

Simply put. I'm asking how to operate two windows. I got as far as splitting it as you can see in the image I attached, but I can't divide it any further.

It's late. I will re-edit this if this is too confusing. Any help please fellow stacks. thanks (Windows 8.0)

Answer (score 0):

> (Windows 8.0)

I assume you are using Windows 8.1? As I didn't think it was possible to split the screen 50/50 in 8.0 (only 70/30)?

Anyway, use <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (period key, same as unshifted <kbd>></kbd> if that's easier to remember) to move the current window to the right. And likewise <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (comma, unshifted <kbd><</kbd>) to go to the left.